# Pyspark - For each ID, I'm looking to filter data that occurs after the data of two id's matching

Tags: pyspark

Disclaimer: I am very new to pyspark.

Here is an example:

Original Dataset

```
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
|install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2 | 
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|21 | 543|
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|35 | 231|
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|23 | 23 |
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:05:21|54 | 654|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|23 | 234|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|12 | 14 |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|54 | 54 |
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
```

All of my data is sorted by `install_id` and `influencer_date_time` in ascending order.

Filtering Condition:

- For each `install_id` find where `id1` and `id2` are the same
- For each `install_id`, **remove** any row that comes after the row you found above.

In the example above, for `install_id` 68483732, `id1` and `id2` are the same in the third row. Because of this, we need to remove row 4.

And for `install_id` 68486103, it would stay as is, since there are no rows that occur after the row with matching `id1` and `id2`.

Here is what the final dataset would look like:

```
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
|install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2 | 
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|21 | 543|
|  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|35 | 231|
|  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|23 | 23 |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|23 | 234|
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|12 | 12 |
|  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|54 | 54 |
+----------+--------------------+---+----+
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: should the id1=54 and id2=54 be there in the output? it follows id1=12 and id2=12, right?

Comment: I've added additional details. Let me know if it still isn't clear.

Comment: @Raghu - There was a typo, now it should make sense. You were interpreting the logic correctly.

Comment: did you get a chance to try any of the answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative-

> Written in scala

### Load the test data

```scala
 val data =
      """
        |install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2
        |  68483732| 2020-05-28 22:56:43|21 | 543
        |  68483732| 2020-05-28 23:21:53|35 | 231
        |  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:03:21|23 | 23
        |  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:05:21|54 | 654
        |  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:06:21|12 | 12
        |  68483732| 2020-05-29 00:07:21|54 | 654
        |  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:37:38|23 | 234
        |  68486103| 2020-06-01 00:59:30|12 | 14
        |  68486103| 2020-06-01 01:59:30|54 | 54
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+
      * |install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2|
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 22:56:43 |21 |543|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 23:21:53 |35 |231|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:03:21 |23 |23 |
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:05:21 |54 |654|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:06:21 |12 |12 |
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:07:21 |54 |654|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:37:38 |23 |234|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:59:30 |12 |14 |
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 01:59:30 |54 |54 |
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- install_id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- influencer_date_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
      * |-- id1: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- id2: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

### drop rows after first matching id1 and id2 in a group

```scala
     val w = Window.partitionBy("install_id").orderBy("influencer_date_time")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df.withColumn("new_col", min(when($"id1" === $"id2", $"influencer_date_time")).over(w))
      .filter($"influencer_date_time".cast("long") - $"new_col".cast("long")<=0)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      * |install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2|new_col            |
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 22:56:43 |21 |543|2020-05-29 00:03:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 23:21:53 |35 |231|2020-05-29 00:03:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:03:21 |23 |23 |2020-05-29 00:03:21|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:37:38 |23 |234|2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:59:30 |12 |14 |2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 01:59:30 |54 |54 |2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      */
```

### drop rows after last matching id1 and id2 in a group

```scala
  // drop rows after last matching id1 and id2 in a group
    df.withColumn("new_col", max(when($"id1" === $"id2", $"influencer_date_time")).over(w))
      .filter($"influencer_date_time".cast("long") - $"new_col".cast("long")<=0)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      * |install_id|influencer_date_time|id1|id2|new_col            |
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 22:56:43 |21 |543|2020-05-29 00:06:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-28 23:21:53 |35 |231|2020-05-29 00:06:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:03:21 |23 |23 |2020-05-29 00:06:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:05:21 |54 |654|2020-05-29 00:06:21|
      * |68483732  |2020-05-29 00:06:21 |12 |12 |2020-05-29 00:06:21|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:37:38 |23 |234|2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 00:59:30 |12 |14 |2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * |68486103  |2020-06-01 01:59:30 |54 |54 |2020-06-01 01:59:30|
      * +----------+--------------------+---+---+-------------------+
      */
```

Comment: This will not work if there are more than one row available after the matching row as you are using unbounded following

Comment: Then this is question for author, what if there are multiple matching `id1` and `id2` . Should we take first one and drop all rows after that or should we take last matching row and drop after that?

Comment: Great answer...using datetime to filter is nice..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the lag function with windowing after comparision

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(1,3,4,1),(1,4,5,5),(1,6,7,8),(2,1,9,2),(2,2,9,9)],schema=['col1','col2','id1','id2'])
w = Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy('col2')
tst_cmp = tst.withColumn("cmp",F.when(F.col('id1')==F.col('id2'),1).otherwise(0))
#%%
tst_flag = tst_cmp.withColumn("flag", F.sum(F.lag('cmp',default=0).over(w)).over(w))
tst_res = tst_flag.where(F.col('flag')==0)
```

Comment: This will not work if there are more than one row available after the matching row.

Comment: the goal is to remove all the rows after a matching row?

Comment: ah, that's a catch.. then this wont work, thanks for the hint..

Comment: @ShubhamJain - have updated the logic.. should work now.. thanks again